# How to use lookup filters to sort results in PythonEve using PyMongo

Tags: python-3.x, flask, pymongo, eve

In PythonEve using MongoDB, how can I get (internally) the last item created in a given collection?

Looking into eve's mongo module `find_one_raw` looks like the way to go. I am trying something like the following without success:

`last = app.data.find_one_raw('aresource',**{"_created": {"sort": 1}})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pymongo driver accepts fairly standard mongo syntax, try the following:

```
collection = app.data.driver.db['collection']

last = collection.find().sort([('_created', -1)]).limit(1)
```

This will sort the documents newest to oldest, and return a cursor with 1 result, that being the newest possible document.Getting the first element (`last[0]`) of the cursor returns a dictionary as intended.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I've updated your answer with the proper syntax for this scenario and added a note on the result.